# Why do eigenvalues of a real $2\times2$ matrices with positive determinant and negative trace have negative real parts?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Consider the real matrix
>   $$
> A=\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix}.
> $$
>   It is said that the real parts of the Eigenvalues of $A$ are all negative if
>   $$
> a+d<0\text{ and }ad-bc>0,
> $$
>   i.e. 
>   $$
> \text{trace }A<0\text{ and }\text{det }A>0.
> $$

How to verify this?

If I consider the characteristic polynomial of $A$ which is
$$
\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda+ad-bc=0,
$$
this has solutions
$$
\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{a+d}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{(a+d)^2}{4}-(ad-bc)}
$$

I think, we now have two possibilities.

(1) $\lambda_{1,2}$ are real if 
$$
ad-bc\leq\frac{(a+d)^2}{4}
$$

In this case, we have
$$
\lambda_{1,2}\leq a+d
$$

and we need $a+d<0$ to have negative real parts.

(2) $\lambda_{1,2}$ are complex.

This is the case if the expression under the root is negative what only can be the case if $ad-bc>\frac{(a+d)^2}{4}>0$. The real part then is $\frac{a+d}{2}$ and this is negative exactly when $a+d<0$.

Summarizing both cases, we have the two conditions
$$
a+d<0\text{ and }ad-bc>0.
$$

Comment: What is your Question??

Comment: My question is if my Argumentation is correct.

Answer (score 3):

First deal with the case where the two eigenvalues $x$ and $y$ are real. In this case $det(A)=xy>0$ implies that $x$ and $y$ are of the same sign, while $Tr(A)=x+y<0$ implies they are both negative.

Now if $x$ and $y$ are nonreal they are conjugated (as they are both roots of the characteristic polynomial). In particular they have the same real part, which is negative, since $Tr(A)<0$ is twice the common real part of $x$ and $y$.